# one hot encoding a whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large numeric dataframe but in fact, it is categorical in which each number represents an adjective.

I need to one_hot_encode all the columns(114 columns) of my dataframe.

can anyone help me with how to do it in python?

this is the dataset:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsqmN.png)

Comment: I assume you're using Pandas so I added the [tag:pandas] tag for you. If that's incorrect, you can [edit]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: `pd.get_dummies(df)`

Comment: @ashkangh I tried that, still it gave me 114 columns, but it supposed to have much more than that after one hot encoding